# CREATE TRIGGER for two tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER  for two tables in Postgres

I am using Postgres. I have two tables here in my database, payroll and `staff_absences`. `staff_absences` is a link table to a payroll table that logs what absence the staff has and to calculate in payroll table.

The staff absent is calculated from `start_date - end_date` by a trigger in the `staff_absences` table. I'm trying to input absences_no into payroll by a trigger.

The trigger is accepted by the schema and I can insert data into `staff_absences` table. However, it gives me this error when I try to update payroll table.

```
{ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "staff_absences"
LINE 1: SELECT NEW.staff_absences.start_date - NEW.staff_absences.en...
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT NEW.staff_absences.start_date - NEW.staff_absences.end_date
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function lowlands_db.pay_trgr() line 4 at assignment}
```

These are the create scripts for payroll and `staff_absences`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE lowlands_db.payroll
(
    payroll_id integer NOT NULL,
    annual_salary numeric NOT NULL,
    appointment_bonus numeric,
    absences_id integer NOT NULL,
    staff_id integer NOT NULL,
    total_monthly_salary numeric,
    monthly_salary numeric,
    absence_no numeric,
    tax numeric,
    CONSTRAINT payroll_pkey PRIMARY KEY (payroll_id),
    CONSTRAINT payroll_staff_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (staff_id)
        REFERENCES lowlands_db.staff (staff_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE lowlands_db.staff_absences
(
    absences_id integer NOT NULL,
    start_date date NOT NULL,
    end_date date,
    cause_of_absences text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    staff_id integer NOT NULL,
    absen_no numeric,
    CONSTRAINT staff_absences_pkey PRIMARY KEY (absences_id),
    CONSTRAINT staff_absences_staff_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (staff_id)
        REFERENCES lowlands_db.staff (staff_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION lowlands_db.asb_pay_trg()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    
    UPDATE lowlands_db.payroll
        SET lowlands_db.payroll.absence_no = new.staff_absences.absen_no
        WHERE lowlands_db.staff_absences.absences_id = NEW.lowlands_db.payroll.absences_id; 
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$;
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION lowlands_db.pay_trgr()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    
    NEW.absences_no = NEW.staff_absences.start_date - NEW.staff_absences.end_date;
    NEW.monthly_salary = ROUND(NEW.annual_salary /12 );
    NEW.tax = ROUND(NEW.monthly_salary * .2);
    NEW.total_monthly_salary = ROUND((NEW.monthly_salary - NEW.tax)+ NEW.appointment_bonus);
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$;
```

your help in advance.

Comment: Assuming `lowlands_db.pay_trgr()` is used by the trigger on `staff_absences` the issue is this `NEW.staff_absences.start_date` and this `NEW.staff_absences.end_date`. Lose the `staff_absences` portions. The  `NEW`  tuple will  have those values from the `staff_absences` table.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian. I did what you said My code now is {BEGIN
 
 NEW.absences_no = NEW.staff_absences.absen_no;
 NEW.monthly_salary = ROUND(NEW.annual_salary /12 );
 NEW.tax = ROUND(NEW.monthly_salary * .2);
 NEW.total_monthly_salary = ROUND((NEW.monthly_salary - NEW.tax)+ NEW.appointment_bonus);
 RETURN NEW;
 END; } but I get this message {ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "staff_absences"
LINE 1: SELECT NEW.staff_absences.absen_no
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT NEW.staff_absences.absen_no
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function lowlands_db.pay_trgr() line 4 at assignment

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the `CREATE TRIGGER` statements for both triggers? ([edit] your question, do not put code into comments).

Comment: Sorry, there is still no `CREATE TRIGGER` code in your question.